# Plotly: How to handle overlapping colorbar and legends?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have a simple graph and I am using Plotly Express Library to draw it. The image is as follows which have two legends overlapping 'Rank' and 'Genre'.

[image]

```
px.scatter_ternary(data_frame = data, a='Length.', b='Beats.Per.Minute', c='Popularity',
               color = 'Rank',
               symbol = 'Genre',
               labels = {'Length.': 'Len', 'Beats.Per.Minute':'Beats'},
               color_continuous_midpoint = 15,
               symbol_sequence = ['circle-open-dot', 'cross-open','triangle-ne'])
```

What can be done to avoid overlapping?

Comment: This is not a question about making room for legends, but rather handle the fact that your ternary plot produces legends based on one variable, and a colorbar based on another variable, and that they are placed on the same `x, y` coordinates. I changed the title to reflect that. Feel free to change it again if you disagree.

Comment: Thanks, @vestland. It is a valid improvement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Short answer:

You can move the colorbar with:

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(yanchor="top", y=1, x=0,
                                          ticks="outside"))
```

---

#### The details:

Since you haven't provided a fully executable code snippet with a sample of your data, I'm going to have to base a suggestion on [a dataset and an example](https://plotly.com/python/ternary-plots/) that's at least able to reproduce a similar problem. Take a look:

[image]

This seems to be the exact same problem that you're facing. To make the plot readable, I would simply move the colorbar using `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar()` like this:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.election()

# figure setup
fig = px.scatter_ternary(df, a="Joly", b="Coderre", c="Bergeron", hover_name="district", 
    color="total", size="total", size_max=15, symbol ='Coderre',
    color_discrete_map = {"Joly": "blue", "Bergeron": "green", "Coderre":"red"},
    )

# move colorbar
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(yanchor="top", y=1, x=0,
                                          ticks="outside",
                                          ticksuffix=" bills"))
fig.show()
```

I hope this solves your real-world problem. Don't hesitate to let me know if not!

Answer (score 6):

In my case;

```
fig = ...
fig.update_layout(legend_orientation="h")
```

solved the problem.

Comment: This did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

For some cases changing the orientation of the color bar to horizontal makes sense and is a quick fix.

```
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(orientation="h"))
```

Comment: This gieves me an error: ```Did you mean "bordercolor"?

Bad property path:
orientation```

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing that error. `orientation` was a valid property in the version I was using. Documentation here: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-orientation