# Plotly in R: How to handle overlapping colorbar and legends?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

This is exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61827165/plotly-how-to-handle-overlapping-colorbar-and-legends), however instead of using Python, I am using R.

How do I avoid having 2 overlapping colorbar legends in plotly in R?

An example of this can be generated by

```
set.seed(123)

x = sample(1:ncol(volcano), size = 50)
y = sample(1:nrow(volcano), size = 50)
z = c()
for(i in 1:50) {z <- c(z, volcano[y[i], x[i]])}

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

plot_ly(z = volcano, type = "surface") %>% 
add_trace(data = df, x = x, y = y, z = z, mode = "markers", type = "scatter3d", 
          marker = list(size = 5, symbol = 104, colorscale = "RdYlBu", autocolorscale = FALSE,
                        colorbar = list(xanchor = "left")), color = ~z,
          legendrank = 0)
```

Which produces

[image: Example of overlapping colorbar legends]

As can be seen by the code snippet neither using `colorbar` or `legendrank` are working, and both legends are plotted in the same location.

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out straight after posting, but will keep it up as it is a useful question I think.

In the `marker` settings, you need to include `colorbar = list(x=0)`

Comment: for python users, you can do `marker = dict(opacity=0.2, colorscale='Inferno', colorbar = dict(x=0))`